# Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing this issue after migrating the java code to AndroidX. Tried with updating the JAVA_HOME in bash profile and using java v1.8, but no luck.

Comment: what is your real problem describe it

Comment: I have migrated my code to AndroidX , after doing that started getting this gradle issue. I have tried multiple solutions from stack overflow itself. One of them is adding JAVA_HOME in bash profile, but that didn't worked.

Comment: post the error, logcat...

Comment: This is the error - 
Cannot change resolution strategy of dependency configuration ':app:compile' after it has been resolved.